# Encode H265 to hvc1 codec

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is the info of my source file:
[image]

I want to keep audio quality and just encode the video track so I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:a copy -c:v libx265 video-h265.mp4
```

This is the result:
[image]

But the codec of the video track is **hev1** . I want it's **hvc1**

Comment: Why do you provide images of text instead of simply copying and pasting it?

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: Text is searchable, can be copied and pasted (often useful for answers), doesn't rely on what I'm assuming is a third-party image host, takes up less space, should be easier and less time consuming for you to do, and it is easier to show the complete console output which you should always provide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

'hev1'/'hvc1' are code points used to signal different packaging of the stream in the container mp4 file. There is no change in the coding itself. It is possible to round trip between the two modes. Try with mp4box :

```
mp4box -raw 1 file.mp4
```

This will extract the stream into a raw HEVC file.

```
mp4box -add file_track1.hvc output.mp4
```

This will reimport the stream using hvc1 if it can.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I forget to answer my question by myself, too

Comment: @cconcolato Is this possible directly in a ffmpeg encoding command without mp4box post-encoding step?

Answer (score 41):

Using the latest `ffmpeg` (`N-87630-ge9f9175-tessus` or building from `HEAD`) you can encode to the MP4 version that macOS High Sierra Quicktime requires by using using `-tag:v hvc1`.

If you have a `hev1`-based mp4 and you need the container to be `hvc1` and you do not want to re-encode it:

```
ffmpeg -i input-hev1.mp4 -c:v copy -tag:v hvc1 -c:a copy output-hvc1.mp4
```

Use ffprobe to confirm the change:

From:

```
~~~~
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x404, 164 kb/s, 29.97 fps,
~~~~
```

To:

```
~~~~
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x404, 164 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
~~~~
```

If you have an *older* `avc1` based mp4, you will need to re-encode it.

`ffprobe` example (`avc1`):

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2778 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
```

Encoding Example:

```
ffmpeg 
    -i input.mp4 \
    -c:v libx265 \
    -preset slow \
    -vf scale="720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" \
    -crf 28 \
    -tag:v hvc1 \
    -c:a aac -b:a 44100 \
    output-hvc1.mp4
```

The key is the `-tag:v hvc1`, without that you will end up with an `hev1`-based container that Quicktime 10.4+ (High Sierra) will not open.

Comment: You can use `brew install ffmpeg --with-x265 --HEAD` to install it using Homebrew.

Comment: @Florian I normally do that, but it is broken, there was a pull request to fix it but it was rejected....

Comment: That's strange! I used the command just before I posted it here.

Comment: Did something change? I did this on High Sierra 10.13.6 and QT 10.4 it still won't play h265. Checked with ffprobe that it indeed was hvc1. My source was an AVI though. Plays fine on VLC. Strange....

Comment: @Jensie No, nothing changed... via ffprobe does it read `...Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 .....` ?

Comment: This really helped me.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing Glad it did 

Answer (score 5):

Add `-tag:v hvc1` as @SushiHangover's answer and `-bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb` to `ffmpeg` command(version 3.4 and later). That will create a QuickTime-compatible mov file.

```
ffmpeg -i input-hev1.mp4 -c:v copy -tag:v hvc1 -bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb -c:a copy output-hvc1.mov
```

Comment: is that all supposed to be on one line?

Comment: what does the `-bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb` part do exactly?

Comment: the ```-bsf:v ...``` part looks unnecessary - "Please note that this filter is auto-inserted for... raw HEVC/H.265 (muxer h265 or hevc) output formats" [link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#hevc_005fmp4toannexb)

Answer (score 0):

I found this question useful, and I am unable to edit this question to replace the images with the text. So adding it here.

```
Input #0. matroska,webm, from 'E:\ffmpeg-20150821-git-45f3d4e-win64-static\60s_test.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: mp42mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND      : mp42
    MINOR_VERSION    : 0  
    ENCODER          : Lavf55.45.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.11, start: 0.000000. bitrate: 4931 kb/s
   Stream #0:0<eng>: Video:h264 <Main>, yuv42p(tv), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc <default>
   Metadata:
     CREATION_TIME   : 2015-98-21 99:21:94
     LANGUAGE        : eng
     HANDLER_NAME    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
     ENCODER         : AVC Coding
   Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
   Stream #0:2: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
```

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2.mj2, from 'E:\ffmpeg-2015082-git 45f3d4e-win64-static\bin\video-h265.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand      : isom
    minor_version    : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder          : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:01:00.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 639 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc <Main> <hev1 / 8x31766568>, yuv420p(tv), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 505 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc <default>
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1 <und>: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / Bx6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 127 kb/s <default>
    Metadata:
      handler_name    :SoundHandler
```