# Video save error in iPhone Gallery for H265 Codec

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, ffmpeg, phphotolibrary

I am using an app in which I am creating a video from my live stream and convert it to Mp4/Mov format and save it to documents directory.

I am using below command to create Mp4 file from video frames.

```
-loglevel trace -r 20 -i inputfile -c:v copy -f mp4 -y -r 20 outputfile
```

When video files are H264 then it is working but having issue when codec type is H265.

App is created in Xamarin iOS. Native code help will also work.

Now I want to save this video from documents directory to iPhone Gallery and share using UIActivityViewController.

It works fine when video codec is H264 but HEVC/H264 video gives me error saying

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)`

while saving to gallery.

I searched a lot and tried too many solutions but nothing works for me.

I am using the below code.

```
NSData videoData = NSData.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString(mFilePath));

                UIVideo.SaveToPhotosAlbum(mFilePath, (string path, NSError errdor) =>
                {
                    mShareVideoUrl = NSUrl.FromString(path);
                


                PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges(() =>
                {
                    //Save Clip to photo library...                    
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.FromVideo(mShareVideoUrl);
                    
                }, (bool success, NSError error) =>
                {
                    if (success)
                    {
                        MxLogger.printLine(MxLogger.LOG_TAG.DEBUG, "Video Saved to gallery");

                        var options = new PHFetchOptions
                        {
                            FetchLimit = 1,
                            SortDescriptors = new[] { new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", false) },

                        };

                        // Get that video url for Photo Library...
                        PHAsset phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(options).FirstOrDefault() as PHAsset;

                        PHVideoRequestOptions requestOptions = new PHVideoRequestOptions();
                        requestOptions.Version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersion.Original;
                        requestOptions.DeliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.Automatic;
                        requestOptions.NetworkAccessAllowed = true;

                        PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestAvAsset(phAsset, requestOptions, (AVAsset asset, AVAudioMix audioMix, NSDictionary info) =>
                        {
                            NSError errorp;
                            AVUrlAsset avurlasset = (AVUrlAsset)asset;

                            mShareVideoUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(mFilePath);

                            if (NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Copy(avurlasset.Url.AbsoluteString, mShareVideoUrl.AbsoluteString, out errorp))
                            {
                                //MxLogger.printLine(MxLogger.LOG_TAG.DEBUG, "Error : " + error);
                            }

                            MxLogger.printLine(MxLogger.LOG_TAG.DEBUG, "Video exported successfully : " + mShareVideoUrl);

                            MxLogger.printLine(MxLogger.LOG_TAG.DEBUG, "Video exported successfully");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MxLogger.printLine(MxLogger.LOG_TAG.DEBUG, "Video Saved to gallery error");

                    }

                });
                });
```

Please guide me what wrong I am doing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "gives me error" - what is the error?  Why have you not included this highly relevant information in your post?

Comment: @Jason: Updated the question. Please help if you can.

Comment: If you are using `H265` (your title does not match your problem statement), then you need to encode to an `hvc1` , not `avc1` or `hev1`

Comment: @SushiHangover: Thank you for the guide. The above tags were the key you mentioned. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152090/encode-h265-to-hvc1-codec

Comment: Same thing is happening for Mjpeg4. Is that any tag related to that as well?