# Problem creating proper mp4 from hevc video frames

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg, mp4, hevc

I have to create an mp4 file from video streams. I am using FFmpeg-kit to use CLI type usage pattern to create mp4 file

I am using the below command

```
-loglevel trace -r 20 -i inputfile -c:v copy -f mp4 -y -r 20 outputfile
```

When input file contains h264 codec video stream then mp4 file created successfully and also saved to photo library in iOS

But when the input file contains hevc(h265) codec video stream then it will create an mp4 file but it will not get stored on photo library

Also tried to convert mp4 to mov using command but it fails by saying invalid data found for processing input file

Please help with what I am missing in command or what I have to pass additionally to create mp4 from hevc video input file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152090/encode-h265-to-hvc1-codec